# Cocos2d image animation not being repeatad

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

This is a code which I used for animation in cocos2d android, **but it doesn't repeat, what to do for that?**

```
 public void animWaterSplash() {    

        OpenPuzzleAnim = CCAnimation.animation("", 0.18f);
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache();
            OpenPuzzleAnim.addFrame(String.format("waterSplash%02d.png", i));
        }
        action1 = CCAnimate.action(OpenPuzzleAnim);
        waterSplash.runAction(action1);
    }
```

Comment: I take it this is cocos2d-android, not cocos2d-iphone? I changed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced same problem but than i made small change and solved the problem. firstly you use CCRepeatForever for repetition and add (_) underscore in your image name. 
In my case i was using same process but when i change the images name.. it worked.

I modify your code with this. Just check it out , may this help you.

```
public void animWaterSplash() {    

        OpenPuzzleAnim = CCAnimation.animation("run", 0.18f);
        OpenPuzzleAnim.addFrame(String.format("waterSplash_01.png")); 
        OpenPuzzleAnim.addFrame(String.format("waterSplash_02.png"));
        OpenPuzzleAnim.addFrame(String.format("waterSplash_03.png"));
        CCAnimate animate = CCAnimate.action(OpenPuzzleAnim);  
        CCRepeatForever repeat =  CCRepeatForever.action(animate);
        waterSplash.runAction(repeat); 
}
```

and if you want to move your object than add one more action like this

```
 public void animWaterSplash() {    

        OpenPuzzleAnim = CCAnimation.animation("run", 0.18f);
        OpenPuzzleAnim.addFrame(String.format("waterSplash_01.png")); 
        OpenPuzzleAnim.addFrame(String.format("waterSplash_02.png"));
        OpenPuzzleAnim.addFrame(String.format("waterSplash_03.png"));
        CCAnimate animate = CCAnimate.action(OpenPuzzleAnim);  
        CCRepeatForever repeat =  CCRepeatForever.action(animate);
        CCAction moveAction = CCMoveBy.action(6.0f,CGPoint.ccp(yourpoints);
        waterSplash.runAction(repeat);
        waterSplash.runAction(moveAction);
}
```

May be its silly but worked for me.you can also try.

Answer (score 0):

U need to put your `action1` into `CCRepeatForever`. And then run that action instead of action1.